# Jhipster Auditing Entities

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster, auditing, jdl

Hello I am using Jhipster to generate my backend code and I'm trying to add auditing fields to my entities, I am aware that my custom entity should extend the `AbstractAuditingEntity` class, but the added fields are not showing in the database but are showing in JPA, do you know how can I solve the issue?
here is the code of the Abstract auditing entity class generated by Jhipster

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdBy", "createdDate", "lastModifiedBy", "lastModifiedDate" }, allowGetters = true)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public abstract T getId();

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Instant getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Instant createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public Instant getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Instant lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

and here the custom entity code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "indicator")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class Indicator extends AbstractAuditingEntity<Long> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer code;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "title", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "titlear", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String titlear;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "titlefr", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String titlefr;

    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "description", length = 500)
    private String description;

    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "descriptionar", length = 500)
    private String descriptionar;

    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "descriptionfr", length = 500)
    private String descriptionfr;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "rating", nullable = false)
    private Integer rating;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "indicators")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "indicators" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Set<Competency> competencies = new HashSet<>();

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Indicator id(Long id) {
        this.setId(id);
        return this;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public Indicator code(Integer code) {
        this.setCode(code);
        return this;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public Indicator title(String title) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        return this;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitlear() {
        return this.titlear;
    }

    public Indicator titlear(String titlear) {
        this.setTitlear(titlear);
        return this;
    }

    public void setTitlear(String titlear) {
        this.titlear = titlear;
    }

    public String getTitlefr() {
        return this.titlefr;
    }

    public Indicator titlefr(String titlefr) {
        this.setTitlefr(titlefr);
        return this;
    }

    public void setTitlefr(String titlefr) {
        this.titlefr = titlefr;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public Indicator description(String description) {
        this.setDescription(description);
        return this;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescriptionar() {
        return this.descriptionar;
    }

    public Indicator descriptionar(String descriptionar) {
        this.setDescriptionar(descriptionar);
        return this;
    }

    public void setDescriptionar(String descriptionar) {
        this.descriptionar = descriptionar;
    }

    public String getDescriptionfr() {
        return this.descriptionfr;
    }

    public Indicator descriptionfr(String descriptionfr) {
        this.setDescriptionfr(descriptionfr);
        return this;
    }

    public void setDescriptionfr(String descriptionfr) {
        this.descriptionfr = descriptionfr;
    }

    public Integer getRating() {
        return this.rating;
    }

    public Indicator rating(Integer rating) {
        this.setRating(rating);
        return this;
    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Set<Competency> getCompetencies() {
        return this.competencies;
    }

    public void setCompetencies(Set<Competency> competencies) {
        if (this.competencies != null) {
            this.competencies.forEach(i -> i.removeIndicator(this));
        }
        if (competencies != null) {
            competencies.forEach(i -> i.addIndicator(this));
        }
        this.competencies = competencies;
    }

    public Indicator competencies(Set<Competency> competencies) {
        this.setCompetencies(competencies);
        return this;
    }

    public Indicator addCompetency(Competency competency) {
        this.competencies.add(competency);
        competency.getIndicators().add(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Indicator removeCompetency(Competency competency) {
        this.competencies.remove(competency);
        competency.getIndicators().remove(this);
        return this;
    }

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Indicator)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Indicator) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Indicator{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", code=" + getCode() +
            ", title='" + getTitle() + "'" +
            ", titlear='" + getTitlear() + "'" +
            ", titlefr='" + getTitlefr() + "'" +
            ", description='" + getDescription() + "'" +
            ", descriptionar='" + getDescriptionar() + "'" +
            ", descriptionfr='" + getDescriptionfr() + "'" +
            ", rating=" + getRating() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

as you can see I have extended the class and the extra fields do appear in the persitance of JPA but whenever I run the server my database is not updated with those fields.

the database is also postgres if that can help

Comment: Are you using a blueprint, module, or your own code to add auditing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MattRaible I'm using the generated code module

Comment: Have you updated the database migrations to add the new fields to the database schema?

Comment: yes, that was exactly my issue, i had to update the changelog files in liquibase to see the changes